# How to decode "application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist" in Qt for drag and drop?

Tags: qt, qt4

I've created a child class of QTreeWidget that I want to be able to drag items from another tree widget too (I want to handle the insertion myself though), as well as from a QListWidget.

I've overridden the dropEvent method in my class, and it looks like the mimetype of the data I'm getting from my QTreeWidget is application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist, how can I decode this to get the items from the tree back out?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can decode it as follows:

```
QByteArray encoded = qMimeData->data("application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist");
QDataStream stream(&encoded, QIODevice::ReadOnly);

while (!stream.atEnd())
{
    int row, col;
    QMap<int,  QVariant> roleDataMap;
    stream >> row >> col >> roleDataMap;

    /* do something with the data */
}
```

The `QMap<int, QVariant>` is what is returned by [`QAbstractItemModel::itemData(index)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#itemData) for the index representing `(row, col)`.

Comment: Also, remember that the encoded data is indexed by roles so to get your actual data back quickly, use `roleDataMap.value(Qt::Role)` and use the appropriate `.to...` from the variant.

Comment: Thank you it is the rigth the solution.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you can use QStandardItemModel to decode the data and get an item back out.  Don't know if this is the best way to do it though:

```
  model = QStandardItemModel()
  model.dropMimeData(event.mimeData(), Qt.CopyAction, 0,0, QModelIndex())
```

Then you can use the item() method from model to retrieve the item and handle it however you want.

Comment: The code needs some fixes though - `QStandardItemModel()` cannot be created, you must use `new` for some reason. And `Qt.CopyAction` should be `Qt::CopyAction`.

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica, gct's code works because it is Python (the question is using PyQt). The changes you mention are needed for C++.

Answer (score 4):

In PySide2 this works for me

```
def dropEvent(self, event):
    if event.mimeData().hasFormat('application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist'):
        data = event.mimeData()
        source_item = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        source_item.dropMimeData(data, QtCore.Qt.CopyAction, 0,0, QtCore.QModelIndex())
        print(source_item.item(0, 0).text())
```