# How to accept Drag and Drop from QListWidget in custom QTextEdit

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop

In my own TextEdit (inherits `QTextEdit`) I implement this DragEventHandler:

```
void CustomTextEdit::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent* e)
{
    qDebug() << "void CustomTextEdit::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent* e)";
    qDebug() << "e->mimeData()->hasText() is" << e->mimeData()->hasText();

    QTextEdit::dragEnterEvent(e);
}
```

Example: When I select text inside the TextEdit and drag it around,
the handler gets called and `hasText()` is `true`.

When I drag an item from a `QListWidget` into the TextEdit the handler also gets called
but `hasText()` is `false`. How can I handle the DropEvent anyway?
(`QDragEnterEvent` basically IS a `QDropEvent`)

I know that this would be done in the DropHandler but my question is
**what information does the DropEvent coming from `QListWidget` contain?**
How can access this information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can ask a `QDragEnterEvent` which formats of mime data it contains using [`QMimeData::formats()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmimedata.html#formats).

For example:

```
const QMimeData *mimeData = e->mimeData();
QStringList mimeFormats = mimeData->formats();
foreach(QString format, mimeFormats)
  qDebug() << format;
```

From this we can see that the event's `mimeData` has the format `application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist`.

The data of any particular format can be retrieved with [`QMimeData::data(QString mimeType)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmimedata.html#data), though in the case of `application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist`, the data is encoded in a pretty specific way. This previous SO question covers decoding the data from the `QByteArray` returned by `QMimeData::data`: [How to decode "application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist" in Qt for drag and drop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723989/how-to-decode-application-x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist-in-qt-for-drag-and-drop)

Comment: Thank you for this excellent answer! It is exactly what I wanted to know.