# How to modify the behavior of Drag'n'Drop in QListWidget (or QListView)

Tags: c++, qt

I have a window with two lists. The items on this image are pre-generated from some test array. Spaces are prepended before the small items to make the whole thing look like tree list:

[image: image description]

User can drag items from left to right. I enabled this in QtDesigner:

[image: image description]

The behavior is then automatic, there's no code of mine, yet it already adds the item to the second list:

[image: image description]

But obviously it just copies the item. Copying the item and adding it at the correct position is fine, but I need to do few things during drop:

- prepend spaces before item display text
- project this change to actual data in the program
- ensure item can't be dropped to the top of the list or into empty list

So **where do I override the function that adds the item after drop?** How do I access the item added by the drop event? How do I cancel the event in case of invalid item?

I tried overriding `QListWidget::dropEvent` but I don't know what code should I write. I looked in the sourcecode of parent classes but I have no idea what they are doing.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/dnd.html

Comment: @Drop How does that solve my problem? I have seen that document already. It doesn't help me with getting the drop data or index offset or otherwise adding the drop action as on screenshots above.

Comment: Well, it explains how to pass data from the drag site the to drop site, including accepting/refusing dnd event and including passing custom data types, with code examples. Just follow the links and it all should be clear.

Comment: Here are some more code examples: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/examples-draganddrop.html

Comment: @Drop None of the examples even **touches** the topic of lists. Lists seem to already create their own data format `application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist` as I found out while reverse-engineering the event. I also do not want to re-implement the whole behavior completely.

Comment: What about this then? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723989/how-to-decode-application-x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist-in-qt-for-drag-and-drop

Comment: @Drop That kind of helped, thanks, but I am still stuck at resolving row offset from the event. I guess I will have to copypaste it from Qt private source files.

Comment: You can make custom dropEvent and add your own functionality. See this [link](https://wiki.qt.io/Custom_QListWidget)

Comment: @neiiic From the question: "*I tried overriding QListWidget::dropEvent but I don't know what code should I write.*"

Comment: You could create a MyListWidget, which inherits from QListWidget, and use that for your right side. Within this Widget you have to reimplement `QWidget::dropEvent(QDropEvent * event)`. Have a look at the Puzzle-Example. (`qtbase\examples\widgets\draganddrop\puzzle\pieceslist.cpp`)

Comment: @BernhardHeinrich Again, overriding `dropEvent` is nothing new for me. Getting the text of dropped item and row index where to add it is what I need.

Comment: @TomášZato another idea, looking from completely different side: implement your target widget's insertion method in a way that when you drop the item there would be no need to worry about prepending spaces etc. (for example, you might inherit from a tree widget, override part of the relevant method and then call inherited one for default behavior). This way you keep default drag'n'drop functionality for a tree, and it calls your custom insertion method. Also, an unrelated note: in proper modern Qt program you don't modify the underlying data manually, but use Model-View-* architecture instead.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you found the essential already, don't know if I missed something but if you are already capable of overloading QListWidget::dropEvent, why don't you handle it as a classical "Add" from your widget?

For example something like:

```
void QListWidget::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event) 
{
    const QMimeData *mimeData = event->mimeData();
    Add(mimeData->text()); // probably the slot you defined for your Add button
}
```

I suppose you already has the validators needed in that slot. I don't think you need to find a specific part of the code adding the element to the list and then overload it, since you have the information that something has been dropped, do everything by yourself frm that point.

Comment: This won't work for two reasons. First the event's text is empty when `QListWidgetItem` is dragged and dropped. Second, the item must be added at specific location under mouse. Your proposal would add the item at the end of list, that's not desired.

Comment: Ok, I see what I missed then ^^. I have not done a lot of Qt recently, but I guess the draw method will be called. Maybe overload the draw to add validators and then call the original draw?

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on this problem for quite a while. Finally found a solution on [this site](https://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/model-view-dnd.html), might not be a pretty solution but still works.

You'd want to create your own class which inherits from `QListWidget`.
Then implement the following methods:

```
QStringList mimeTypes() const override

QMimeData *mimeData(const QList<QListWidgetItem *> items) const override

bool dropMimeData(int index, const QMimeData *data, Qt::DropAction action) override
```

The first two functions are for sending your data (dragging the row), and the last one is for getting the data.
Notice that `dropMimeData` gets the index of which the user dropped his row/rows

In my case, I don't need the *style* of the text, I just need the text itself.
So my functions look like these:

```
QStringList mimeTypes() const override
{
    QStringList types;
    types << "application/vnd.text.list";
    return types;
}

QMimeData *mimeData(const QList<QListWidgetItem *> items) const override
{
    if (items.empty()) return nullptr;

    QMimeData *mimeData = new QMimeData();
    QByteArray encodedData;
    QDataStream stream(&encodedData, QIODevice::WriteOnly);

    for (QListWidgetItem * item: items) {
        if (item->text() != "") {
            stream << item->text();
        }
    }

    mimeData->setData("application/vnd.text.list", encodedData);
    return mimeData;
}

bool dropMimeData(int index, const QMimeData *data, Qt::DropAction action) override
{
    // Checking if we should handle the data
    if (!data->hasFormat("application/vnd.text.list"))
        return false;
    if (index == -1)
        return false;
    if (action == Qt::DropAction::IgnoreAction)
        return false;

    // Decoding the data
    QByteArray encodedData = data->data("application/vnd.text.list");
    QDataStream stream(&encodedData, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QStringList newItems;
    int rows = 0;

    while (!stream.atEnd()) {
        QString text;
        stream >> text;
        newItems << text;
        ++rows;
    }

    //Add the items in the desired rows
            
    return true;
}
```

Now as I said, for me I don't need the *style* so I use `application/vnd.text.list` or `text/plain` as the *Mime Type*, you should check the right one for you in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types).